# How to fix Storage Module Cmdlet when they can't run on Powershell Windows 10

Tags: powershell

Any one know How to fix Storage Module Cmdlets when then can't run on powershell over Windows 10 ?

I have try all Cmdlets like `get-disk` , `get-volume` but all gives the following massage

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.HUPCHONGFURNITU\Documents> get-volume
```

> get-volume : Invalid property 
>           + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (MSFT_Volume:ROOT/Microsoft/...age/MSFT_Volume) [Get-Volume],
>   CimException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041031,Get-Volume

```
PS C:\Users\administrator.HUPCHONGFURNITU\Documents> Get-Disk
```

> Get-Disk : Invalid property 
>       + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (MSFT_Disk:ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/Storage/MSFT_Disk) [Get-Disk],
>   CimException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041031,Get-Disk

Comment: You problem may come from the fact that your WMI repository is corrupted. [Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8ed26d46-9994-4052-a307-5b071805aea8/wmi-corrupt-how-to-reinstallrepair) is a Microsoft Article, and [here](https://superuser.com/a/1152468/80875) is a way to use this article.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if VSS and/or SMPHost services are disabled, the MSFT_Volume namespace will not be rebuilt during a WMI repair.
During the repair that JPBlank suggested, also do these commands before you clear the WBEM repository:

sc config vss start= demand

sc config smphost start= demand

sc stop SMPHost

sc stop vss

This will set them both to demand start and make sure they are not running before you clear the repository

I wrote a twitter thread on this as well:
https://twitter.com/YarnoSG/status/1646171772952117248